VS code terminal appears case sensitive?
I've just started learning python on the ATBS course and have been going for almost 2 months. I'm having trouble with the terminal and command prompt on my PC which is running on windows 10
I have a python file called mClip.py and I am trying to pass an argument called 'agree'. I am trying to run this on the terimal.
Scenario 1: If I type:
PS G:\my drive\atbs\6> python mclip.py agree*
then I get an error saying: C:\Users\Cool-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'G:\my drive\atbs\6\mclip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
However Scenario 2: if I type the exact same thing buy capitalise some letters then it successfully runs the python file. I.e. if I type:
PS G:\My Drive\ATBS\6> py mclip.py agree
then the terminal executes the file without problems
The funny thing is whether I type scenario 1 or 2 into my laptop (instead of PC), the terminal is able to execute the file without problems. The only difference I can think of between my laptop and PC is that the laptop is running windows 11 and PC is running windows 10.
I thought that the terminal wasn't case sensitive so why does the command work on my PC when I capitalise some of the letters?
Basically if I type the exact same thing into the terminal but capitalise some of the letters the file is able to be executed without any problems. I only have this problem on my PC which is running windows 10 not my laptop which is running windows 11

SIMILAR EXPERIENCE:
I experienced a similar issue not too long ago accessing Java classes via command prompt. In my situation I had issues with this:
javac C:\Users\example user\Projects\School\Java\MyClass.java

Time after time I continued to get errors that the file path was not found, but it ended up working after I capitalized the folder and added spacing like this:
javac "C:\Users\Example User\Projects\School\Java\MyClass.java

SOLUTION:
Use the Python launcher itself:
py "G:\my drive\atbs\6\mClip.py" agree

Double check case sensitivity despite it not usually being an issue on windows:
python "G:\My Drive\ATBS\6\mClip.py" agree

Last but not least, enter the directory:
cd "G:\my drive\atbs\6"

and try and execute it from there..
python mClip.py agree

This should work.

Yeah all of your suggestions work! I was just curious as to why it was being case sensitive, but I guess that remains a mystery!
